# Load File using Apache Jena with Blazegraph as a TripleStore

Tags: java, dataset, jena, blazegraph

For a project I have to use Apache Jena as an API and Blazegraph as a triple store, but I have problems when I load my file by using `RDFConnection.load`

```
    String APIUrl = "http://10.13.102.52:9999/blazegraph/namespace/ProjBD/sparql/ProjBD/sparql";
    RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(APIUrl);
    try {
        conn.load("tp4.ttl");
        QueryExecution qExec = conn.query("select * WHERE {?x ?y ?z}") ;
        ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
        while(rs.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = rs.next() ;
            Resource s = qs.getResource("x") ;
            System.out.println("Resource : " + s) ;
        }
        qExec.close() ;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        conn.close();
    }
```

This code leads to :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException:
>   500 - Server Error
>
> at conn.load("tp4.ttl")

Can you help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: A 500 error code from an HTTP request mean there is a problem with the remote server.  500 is "Internal Server Error". Check the server logs.